# What would cause an ADC to stick on an arbitrary value?

Tags: analog, adc, differential, load-cell

I have a differential ADC (HX710) that I am using to interface a load cell. The wiring is as follows with (J4) going to the load cell: [image]

Mostly, this reads very reliably and accurately. However, intermittently the ADC reading will stick at a seemingly arbitrary range of values (ie. not a power of 2) that would normally represent a very high weight (but not a max reading with respect to the ADC's range). I can't consistently get the circuit into this state. It seems almost random - say every 20th power cycle?

During this failure mode, I can completely unplug the load cell from the system and the ADC will still be floating in this high range.

Under normal circumstances, running the ADC without a load cell returns just the expected unweighted value bouncing around in the noise floor.

Is there a reason that a differential amplifier, like this, might get stuck in a high range intermittently?

Comment: Does it latch for minutes on end disconnected? Also, check if shorting pins 3 and 4 makes it go away. Are there decoupling caps?

Comment: Does the failure mode start as soon as the device is powered up (5% chance), and continue until the device is unpowered? That could point towards a power sequencing issue somewhere in the system.

Comment: @DKNguyen good point, shorting pins 3 and 4 does not change the reading as it does when the ADC is functioning as excepted.

Comment: @MarkU the failure isn't necessarily always right on power up. Sometimes it will drop into this state during normal function.

Comment: What is driving LoadCellEnable?

Comment: Ehhhh, well seems like something with the ADC itself but I didn't see anything obvious in the datasheet.

Comment: @crj11 a 3.3V logic MCU, specifically: CY8C4127LQI-BL453

Comment: Are the zero ohm resistors in the schematic really zero ohms on the board?

Comment: Maybe it is not the ADC but your code?

Comment: @DKNguyen would the ADC driver cause intermittent failures like this? Would it be reasonable that my timing is juuuust right and spills over intermittently?

Comment: @epietrowicz What are you referring to when you say "ADC driver"? Just the signal source? I don't see why the signal source would cause the ADC to behave that way. I'm betting if you just run it with any other signal source you will see the same behaviour. Stick a pot divider on the ADC. Just out of curiosity, do you still get the hanging if you short across the inductor?

Comment: @DKNguyen When I say "ADC driver" I am referring to the HX710-DAT-MISO and HX710-CLK signals that are used to interface with the ADC from the MCU. I can't seem to get the circuit back into a stuck state this morning, but in the past I have stuck a fixed voltage source across pins 3 & 4 to no avail. Is it possible I just got a "bad batch" of ICs? I have never had failures so intermittent with faulty electrical components.

Comment: I don't know, man. The next time it locks up I would just never power it down and do things like probe the communication lines to see if the ADC is actually responding and to make sure microcontroller hasn't locked up or something.

Comment: Have you looked with a scope at the voltage on Vref and VccMain when you turn the LoadCellEnable on and off?  The inductor could be causing spikes that occasionally lock up the ADC.

Comment: @crj11 Great, thought! Unfortunately (fortunately, depends on how you look at it) after just scoping it, the rising edge looks very clean. Almost no overshoot / ringing.

Comment: @crj11 Also triple checked all of the component values in the circuit with no unexpected results.

Comment: Since R2 is 0 ohms, you are putting a relatively high current load on the GPIO of the MCU when you pull LoadCellEnable low.  When the MCU drives LoadCellEnable low, the base of U2 is Vbe below VccMain and you are pulling that down with the GPIO.  Whether or not that is causing your issue, I think R2 should be something more reasonable, like 1K.

Answer (score 4):

This ended up being a software problem. The HX710 has two modes: A) differential input B) DVDD-AVDD measurement. You set the mode for the next conversion period by the amount of PD_SCK trailing pulses in the current conversion period. This is shown on page 5 of the datasheet:

[image: datasheet screen shot]

In the driver code, I neglected to disable interrupts during the data clock out period. This was the cause of the intermittent failures. It seems that interrupting during the clock out sequence would sometimes cause the ADC to begin reading out DVDD-AVDD instead of the differential input. That explains why I would see it hang at an arbitrary value not responding to any inputs from the load cell.

Disable global interrupts while driving time sensitive peripherals!

Lesson learned.